# Should we use Interceptors for error handling in gRPC client?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, grpc, grpc-c#

I have an Asp.Net Core 6 WebApi which makes gRPC calls to a Grpc Service.

I want to implement error handling so that it filters out sensitive information and returns only useful data when an error occurs.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/interceptors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#grpc-interceptors-versus-middleware) - I understand that on the **Grpc Server** an Interceptor is the only way to catch a gRPC error.

On the client, however, any RpcException will be caught by the general exception handers as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#exception-handler).

I see there is an example [here](https://anthonygiretti.com/2020/03/31/grpc-asp-net-core-3-1-global-error-handling-in-grpc-grpc-status-codes/) for Client side interceptor.

But since I don't need to log every call - I see no point in it for my purposes.

Does anyone see a reason to use an Interceptor to catch errors on the **Grpc Client**?

Comment: Its an interesting question, I have been thinking about error handling for my gRPC app for a while, so far I had no problems with simply using a try / catch on the client side. The following is an excerpt from the book Practical gRPC:  "Any kind of error that could happen will be translated to an RPC error, not just those where the server has explicitly returned an error code. For example, If there are connection errors, GRPC::Unavailable will be raised. " So maybe a try / catch is enough on client-side?

Comment: Though there is also an implementation example for a client error handler interceptor in the MS docs:  [ErrorHandlerInterceptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/interceptors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#awaiting-response-in-client-interceptor)